# Can I change the tooltip's default action of Kendo UI grid in MVC?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

In the default action,When I put my mouse  on the `<td>` in the **Tool tip column**, the tooltip will show the content.But Now what I want  is only when I click the `<td>` ,it will show the content.And when I click the mouse outside the `<td>`,the content will disapper.The demo is here:[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/whoamiwho/2dzUb/4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add `showOn: "Click"` and `autoHide: false` to the setup of the tooltip:

```
var toolTip = $('#grid').kendoTooltip({
     showOn: "click",
     autoHide: false,
    filter: ".tooltip",
    beforeShow: function (e) {
        if ($(e.target).data("name") === null) {
            // don't show the tooltip if the name attribute contains null
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    },
    content: function (e) {
        // may be get the content from server using ajax event
        var row = $(e.target).closest("tr");
        var dataItem = grid.dataItem(row);

        return "<div><table><tr><td role='gridcell'>dd</td></tr><tr><td role='gridcell'>dd</td></tr></table>Hi, this is a tool tip for id " + dataItem.Id + "! </div>";
    }
}).data("kendoTooltip");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2dzUb/7/

Comment: It seems not work.When I click the `td`,the tooltip content quickly show and hide.